# Whats the best way to test class with external dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the following class:

```
public class XXX {
    public <T> List<T> loadXXXList(Class<T> type, String fileName) {
        try {
            return new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(new FileReader(fileName)).withSeparator('X')
                    .withType(type).build().parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error occurred while loading object list from file " + fileName);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to test it or restructure it for testing, unit or integration. I was thinking to create a new function in the class that returns CsvToBeanBuilder that I can mock to throw exception or on .parse() to return a list?
something like:

```
public class XXX {
    public <T> List<T> loadXXXList(Class<T> type, String fileName) {
        try {
            return SOMETHING.parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error occurred while loading object list from file " + fileName);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
    public SOMETHING something(type,filename){
          return new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(new FileReader(fileName)).withSeparator('X')
                    .withType(type).build()
}
}
```

But somehow Im not convinced that this looks good and it seams it just big complication for something small, it seams im just moving the logic on a different place. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should not expose nor mock internal implementation details like CsvToBeanBuilder.
Your real external dependency is the filesystem, which you need to generalize before mocking in unit tests, because creating temporary files in tests is a code smell.

Try to refactor your class to accept an InputStream instead of a file path. This way, you can write a unit test which works entirely in memory.